# Syntax error for if-else statement in html.haml file

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement, haml, syntax-error

I am using haml to code out the following code. I basically have a bunch of nested if-else statements in my index.html.haml file. However I keep getting a syntax error for the code below.

```
- if current_user
  :javascript
    window.is_logined_in = true;
    window.currentUserJSON = #{@current_user_json};
    //Getting syntax error for the line below
    - if window.currentUserJSON.user.following_count == 293 && window.currentUserJSON.user.answer_count == 276
      window.complete_orientation = true;
    - else
      window.complete_orientation = false;
- else
  :javascript
    window.is_logined_in = false;
```

[image]

How can I modify my code to resolve this syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use the `-` prefix inside the `:javascript` block like this.
You are literally writing the code to javascript and that's causing the error,
but you should be able to do that without the prefixed `-`, as it is already javascript.

```
- if current_user
  :javascript
    window.is_logined_in = true;
    window.currentUserJSON = #{@current_user_json};
    //Getting syntax error for the line below
    if (window.currentUserJSON.user.following_count == 293 
        && 
        window.currentUserJSON.user.answer_count == 276
    ) {
      window.complete_orientation = true;
    } else {
      window.complete_orientation = false;
    }
- else
  :javascript
    window.is_logined_in = false;
```

The javascript code itself is a bit verbose, but it should do the job.